# copy multiple row data in single cell in excel no longer working for me

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I used to be able to copy and paste multi-line content in Excel into a single cell, all I need to do is double click the new cell or use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and paste using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

However this is no longer working for me.  Every time I copy multi-line data and double click the new cell or use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> the paste option is no longer available to paste and the selected cell loose the dotted flashing border around my selected copy data.

This has just started happening. Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this happening in all workbooks or one specifically? What version of Excel? Has there been a recent update?

Comment: Do you have a wireless keyboard? I have seen this behavior when the battery needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Test <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in another program, in Word it should repeat something you just typed. Just to ensure your keyboard is ok.